# Problemas com arquivos adicionais no Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, arquivo, pyinstaller

Tô construindo um **EXE** com o modo **OneFile** do **Pyinstaller** (pelo auto-py-to-exe). Eu preciso que dois arquivos sejam adicionados, um **.py** de onde o principal vai puxar as funções e uma **imagem JPEG** pra que o background do computador seja trocado. Quando importo o arquivo .py consigo usar todas as funções normalmente, mas quando declaro a imagem como `bg = 'bg.jpg'` no início do código ele não consegue encontrar o arquivo. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: É retornado algum erro? Se sim, qual?

Comment: É retornado o erro básico de arquivo não encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para adicionar os arquivos necessários, como são apenas 2, porque não codifica-los para base64 e adicionar no próprio código/script, portando nele mesmo os arquivos?

Fazendo assim, para em tempo de execução, vc vai decodificar direto no caminho e com o nome que precisar:

```
img_data = b'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'
import base64
with open('c:\\caminho\\completo\\para\\pasta\\nome_desejado.png', 'wb') as fh:
          fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```

---

**Obs.: 1)** Funciona para **`Python 2.7`** e no **`Python 3.x`**

**Obs.: 2)** Fonte [StackOverFlow/En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python), pergunta [**2323128**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python)

---

---

> - **update** strings em base64 ***listadas*** e *não em uma só linha*...

**Obs.:** Para obter a string/codificada/base64 de um arquivo qualquer via linha de comando ou para decodificar/string/base64, caso queira testar, use:

```
:: codifica arquivo ::
certutil -encode e:\pasta\onde\tens\arquivo\para\codificar.png & e:\pasta\salva\codificado.b64 && type d:\pasta\salvar\codificado.b64 | find /v "-" | clip 

:: decodifica arquivo ::
certutil -decode e:\pasta\onde\tens\arquivo\codificado.b64 d:\pasta\onde\salvar\arquivo\decodificado.b64
```

---

```
b64_txt=b"""
           iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAE8AAABPCAYAAACqNJiGAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
           AARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAEnQAABJ0Ad5mH3gAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3
           YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlxyWU8AAADKGlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnht
           cAAAAAAAPD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6
           TlRjemtjOWQiPz4gPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIg
           eDp4bXB0az0iQWRvYmUgWE1QIENvcmUgNS42LWMwMTQgNzkuMTU2Nzk3LCAyMDE0
           LzA4LzIwLTA5OjUzOjAyICAgICAgICAiPiA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0
           dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPiA8cmRm
           OkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25z
           LmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5h
           ZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtbG5zOnhtcD0i
           aHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLyIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0i
           eG1wLmRpZDpGQTUxNkE3OTUwMTUxMUU1QTM4MTk5MTZBMTYzQTE5NiIgeG1wTU06
           SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDpGQTUxNkE3ODUwMTUxMUU1QTM4MTk5MTZBMTYz
           QTE5NiIgeG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgMjAxNCAo
           TWFjaW50b3NoKSI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlE
           PSJ4bXAuaWlkOkMzRjNFMkU4OTU0NzExRTQ5RDc2QjZGRjI5QUEyODdEIiBzdFJl
           Zjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOkMzRjNFMkU5OTU0NzExRTQ5RDc2QjZGRjI5
           QUEyODdEIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBt
           ZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+C29uiwAACDZJREFUeF7tmguMFPUdx7/z
           2ucdx2O5Ig/lIaGCIlHEU0GqqNjAFdtqrY/Wap9WWk1KEQq1qSBGhFDUa7WNxTRt
           k0oTVKQVG4uaKNiirbaQAvZA8FHhDpHb3dnH7Ex//9/8925BiJbZndm180mG29//
           P8fuffN7/mcVh0DICaHKnyEnQCieB0LxPBCK54FQPA+E4nkgFM8DoXgeCMXzQCie
           B0LxPBCK54FQPA80nHhOupuuA9IKloYSz9q1CenFQ2HeN0OuBEvDiJd/dC7Mjk9D
           6T8c9vtvI79untwJjoYQzzn8LgrPdZBww6AoKpTEALLvh935orwjGBpCPKXfJxCf
           +zQc8rgywgMzHTOlFQwNE7b6aZci0nYjHPN9ttkD4wOQXX4220HQUAUjevVPoSQH
           wbEKbCtGFHbXHuSfXMS239SdeE7JQmnnn6X1QZIL/katyn6Un1spScp/f1oBe+9W
           tv2k7sQzV7Qhs3oGilvWyJWjMGKIf3VtRf5TOP9l77tE2v5RV+LlfvVl2O/thTZ4
           DHLUmuR/d7PcORL99NkwJl8DJ3eYbUWlPyPWjOyK89j2i7oRr7DpJyhu/S0VgRZR
           DaC2DEXxlbXIrpom7ziS2HUPUxJspjAvsq2QR9r7dyD/1BK2/aCuHnqbP5sFi3o3
           tSklVygHFrLCtdD0o50UsnG56uLk00jfnuKwVUhwSoTsucnbX4Y69Ax5V+2oq7CN
           37wBkem3kAD7+gpCJEGfUkPP/BTsN//Oa2WUaBPiX/kNNdH/kQsy/62a7to1pu4K
           RnT2UsRvehQOeZBjl3hN0QwoLUOQuXcKipspXCvQJ30exsQ5lP962FZIaEQTvghY
           t99VEeGXXXYmFwJFj7qLIizJy4xzrkPsmofcNUn6jlH0r8NCC+x0F6IzFyJyyXy2
           a0Hdf9Ens+STcLKHoJCIZZzse1BbxyHxvRfkiruWXjgEyoARR+a/Rf/ge2tBYGEr
           8lfpnW3SOj7JH/4L2innsCeVEQcD9sE9SC8e7hYUuRb70ho4Pe+y3Zv/Vk517RoQ
           mHg56uGyyybCvH8GSvtekavHJv6t9YhcdOsxComO9ILBsPe9zGvG5GthnHY5V2EB
           5z9NR+aes9iuNoGErX1gFzKUz9T+w2hOzbthmBqD6Jx7oI8//kmJtW0DzJ9/jjxq
           mCsM4Tg2FZd9iH3hARgXfIPX0otHsLAo0QxMfWDi1k1QT5rAe9UkEPHMjpkUstu5
           sS0jml3HPAQ1PgCR2UtgTLle7hyJ8L7s3VRIqE35QCGhqSN27S/4qD49LwXt9MuQ
           mLvRvacGBCPeL6+G9dpjlKcGApGkm+Aljm1RTIuxS0Xk8kUUrre5G0eRWToeTubg
           UYWExG8dS4XkRZTeeg3asIlypzYEVm1FuBUeX4jC8x1u/qJRi2dUiWPbQL4HTtFE
           5FPfRaT9LvRJ7GI+NAfW68/RRDJYrpBnHnqL7v8Op4BaUxetSuGZFSg8fTe9Inli
           /XrzmUCIDFFRKS/q597AoiiJ/nKX9P3Dj+l3l1EepDxXyEAdPgmJb/9R7taWuhCv
           THHLI8hvuIPClqaFeEtvwyvgj0le6GS6oE+Yhehnl1OROZX3rO1P8Vwsik5SzMA+
           UVfilbH+uQH5xxdwLyf6t97CIKCPyxU60w3t5LMRveJeaKPauGdUW05y86hP1KV4
           ZUpv/AX5dd+nn3/l43cWsbK4WAW3zWlKITFvC5TmVrnjD/6JR29jPnwl9DPmQBt9
           PtTBbsh9FOyuTuQfm08euZ5ETPHRVLlC8+GBeRhNy/smEL/wTbzSG1uRXTWVWwvh
           MUrJgjpiEgk5la42qKMugPphnkO5MCdEfOkRKiwtVKGT3NZEZ90JY9qxT51riW/i
           FZ5djcJGqopUTQX8tnaREhxdNAmIPCaqrEpeKTxTH3ke1DHTKFQjfH8l4gMXqLAU
           nllJv2uheXXe3fAZ38QzH2znHMb9XEXeqoTbEnGsLh4tiomjmOOCoZ8qvJNCnQQV
           hwSVWK8/T/sXSstffBMv/8QPYO16Fs6br8KhYZ09SnMv7uuOJ6jIaUJQMaeKAkHt
           ipoazeGujpyCyPlfk3f6j38FowL7wL9R6qQRajddnS/A3r+T5ty4K6ZOvV1Z0OMg
           nu1yqHe/jeYHff/4vVRFvN+vXYtYzB3yLcvChPHjMXbc/3YAKY6l7N2bSdDNHIpO
           uss9OGBBhYca5JwV4xt5o9pvCLcoZXbt2IFt27dD13W2c7kcrrzqKn5dC6pynieE
           i8fjfInXutE3GXxUtBFnwbjwFsRu+DWaluxF88oexL++DsbFt0GjkQs09NuH3+G+
           js/r6BJ5sBLxvkd/lloS2GHoh0Jhq42djuilCxD/5hPUx3UjeedexK5fA6PtRj7T
           U0+eIm8OhvoV7xioyYHUZLcj+pllSC58FcbkL8qdYKhKznty/XoOE0GxWMQ4ynej
           Ro9mW1DYeBc1t4upx6teGDmUz2JXLEVkZt83pHZ3dmIH5T1Dpg3TNDG7vZ1f1wJf
           PE80xmr/VrqGV/Fq7W24g6Khwrbe8EU8PkKiGbTqF/2/QeJLzivteQkl6t1QeS7n
           FRJOo7FMG3muXPA/5/kinl98LAvGx5WaiKdWPAXzE7/ft+phWyqVkEqlMHDQINji
           8aFPCOEOdnejq6sLmuYeKjRczhMIAf0UrowQsCycoCFznvgDRNL2+6oUzg/CguGB
           qoRt5XlePVHr87yqiPf/Shi2HgjF80AongdC8TwQiueBUDwPhOJ5IBTPA6F4HgjF
           80AongdC8TwQiueBUDwPhOKdMMB/AddRlUWCFyu0AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"""
with open('c:\\caminho\\completo\\para\\pasta\\nome_desejado.png', 'wb') as fh:
          fh.write(base64.decodebytes(b64_txt))
```

---